Issue accessing app from gateway api controller in eks
I have configured EKS cluster and integrate gateway api controller. I have defined gateway class, gateway and service as well. when i am trying to access my service using dns name of vpc service i am getting error like,

So what is major problems here.
below is my configurations,
my gatewayclass
apiVersion: gateway.networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: GatewayClass
metadata:
  name: amazon-vpc-lattice
spec:
  controllerName: application-networking.k8s.aws/gateway-api-controller

my gateway
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: mydemo
spec:
  gatewayClassName: amazon-vpc-lattice
  listeners:
  - name: http
    protocol: HTTP
    port: 80

my httproute
apiVersion: gateway.networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: HTTPRoute
metadata:
  name: direction-flow
spec:
  parentRefs:
  - name: mydemo
    sectionName: http
  rules:
  - backendRefs:
    - name: direction
      kind: Service
      port: 80
    matches:
    - path:
        type: PathPrefix
        value: /direction


myservice
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: direction
  labels:
    app: direction
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: direction
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: direction
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: direction
        image: patelsaheb/hello:v2
       

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: direction
spec:
  selector:
    app: direction
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 8080

Thank You
